# Django rendering multilingual manytomany fields

Tags: django, multilingual

I'm quite new on using Django and I have some trouble to render specific manytomany items as forms in respect to their language. What I tried to do is the following.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class failure_example_manytomany(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(...)
    chinese_name = models.Charfield(...)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name       #problem is on this return value

class attaching_model(models.Model):
    (...)
    normal_field = models.Charfield(_('translatable_name_here'), max_length=128)
    manytomany_field = models.ManyToManyField(failure_example_manytomany, blank=True, verbose_name=_('translatable_name_here'))
    (...)
```

I turned il8n on and it successfully translate the form's name into chinese. Yet I failed to change the return value of my manytomany model according to the chosen language. What can I do. I don't wanna hardcode the form into my templates since it would be tedious.

---

Since someone say it is impossible it turns out to be another question.
How can I render my attaching_model as form where it render the display name of the choice of manytomany change according the user defined language?

This is what I currently get. (Gah! Why? It refrain me to post pics) Please assume [] as checkboxes. Below is what django rendered. (or image link [here](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/f0c4/q5piuk90qkf25246g.jpg))

```
上課地點: 
[] Yuen Long District
[] Tuen Mun District
[] Tsuen Wan District
[] Kwai Tsing District
[] North District
[] Tai Po District
```

with verbose name, it successfully translated to "上課地點", but it unable to traslate the name of choices it give eg "Kwai Tsing District". I hope to find a way to translate them too.

**Summary of question: Find a way to translate ManyToManyField options**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many week, I finally found a perfect solution for this.
I compatible with static i18n translation. My codes looks relatively clean and it did the job! It change language according chosen LANGUAGE_CODE

```
#models.py
class manytomany(models.Model):
    name_zh = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class attaching_model(models.Model):
    normal_field = models.Charfield(_('translatable_name_here'), max_length=128)
    manytomany_field = models.ManyToManyField(manytomany, blank=True, verbose_name=_('translatable_name_here'))

#forms.py
class attaching_modelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=attaching_model

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lang_code = kwargs.pop('lang_code')
        if lang_code == 'zh-tw': #since model name doesn't accept hyphens
            lang_code = 'zh'
        super(attaching_modelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['manytomany_field'].choices =  manytomany.objects.values_list('id','name_%s' % lang_code)

#views.py
form = attaching_modelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,  lang_code = translation.get_language()) #calling the bound/unbound form
```